# Issue with Pointer to an fstream in C++

Tags: c++, file, pointers, fstream

I have an issue with my code below I am trying to use pointer to file stream to write some text in to the file, but the code below does not write in to file, I have tried without pointer to `fstream` which worked fine, but with pointer I can't see any changes in my text file but the code compile successfully.

```
fstream  *io =  new  fstream("FILE/myFile.txt"  ,  ios_base::in | ios_base::out);
  if(!io -> is_open()){
        cout << "Could not open file or file does not exist!" << endl;
        exit(1);
  }
 *io << "Hello World"
```

Comment: Why are you creating a pointer to a file stream?

Comment: Did you tried `std::flush`?

Comment: You may want to try: `(*io) << "Hello World\n";`.  The '\n' will help flush the output buffer.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews The OP way not want a newline in the output file.  `std::flush` would flush the buffer always.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: actually, there is nothing special about newlines in C++. The standard certainly doesn't mandate any flushing of streams when using `'\n'`. The C streams do have a line buffering mode (`_IOLBF`) but unless stream buffers are implemented in terms of `FILE*` even that won't help and the `_IOLBF` isn't the default anyway (I think it is by default only set for `stdout`).

Answer (score 4):

Streams buffer the output. If the stream isn't flushed, the output is never written. Since the string written is tiny it will be buffered. The destructor of the stream would flush the stream as would filling the buffer. As written, the pointer is leaked and the stream is never destroyed and, thus, not flushed.

The fix to your problem is in order of preference:

1. Do not use pointers.
2. Use a smart pointer, e.g., `std::unique_ptr<std::ofstream>` to hold the stream.
3. `delete` the stream object at the end of the program (this is easy to forget and using automated distruction is much preferable).
4. At least, `close()` the stream using `io->close()`. Not `delete`ing the stream would be a resource leak.
5. Flushing the stream using `*io << std::flush` should still write the buffer. This approach would leak memory as the previous approach but additional also leak a file descriptor.

Personally, would go with approach 1. If I absolute had to use pointers which never happened to me with stream, I would use 2. Everything else would technically work but is likely to result in resource leaks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the file :
`io->close();`
If you don't close the file, it will not flush data on the disk.
When you you fstream object on the stack, when the object goes out of scope, it close the file (in the distructor).

Comment: Thanks alangab, you have solved my problem i closed the file after write and i can see changes in to file......Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is probably only a problem of buffer: you need to flush the stream in order to be sure everything is written in the file. The following snippet works fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  ofstream* f = new ofstream("out.dat");

  if(! f->is_open())
  {
    cerr << "Impossible to open the file" << endl;
    exit(-1);
  }

  *f << "Hello, world!" << flush;

  f->close();

  delete f;

  return 0;
}
```

Do not forget that to every `new`, a `delete` should follow!